# Active admin Error! I don't have views folder found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

first time to use active-admin. I just follow the tutorial of railscast. after I install active-admin and some configuration then navigate to "localhost:3000/admin".. I got some errors.

this is the error.

```
ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Showing /home/eebasadre20/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/active_admin-fc1874f7d3b4/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)**strong text**
```

I don't know where the views located. In my views folder only layouts folder is existing.

```
<h2><%= render_or_call_method_or_proc_on(self, active_admin_application.site_title) %> <%= title t('active_admin.devise.login.title') %></h2>

    <% scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_name) %>
    <%= active_admin_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: send(:"#{scope}_session_path"), html: { id: "session_new" }) do |f|
      f.inputs do
        resource.class.authentication_keys.each_with_index { |key, index|
          f.input key, label: t('active_admin.devise.'+key.to_s+'.title'), input_html: { autofocus: index.zero? }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common solution to the issue is to either

- remove `gem 'meta_search'` from `Gemfile`

or

- remove `gem 'meta_search'` from `Gemfile`
- add `gem "formtastic", github: "justinfrench/formtastic"` to
  `Gemfile`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for reminding. I'm new here in stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @Pepeng you can also upvote/downvote any others questions/answers